# Caliburn Micro Navigation with IoC

Tags: c#, navigation, inversion-of-control, caliburn.micro

If I have a view model such as:

```
public interface IMainMenuViewModel
{
    bool CanDoAction1 { get; }
    void DoAction1();
}

public class MainMenuViewModel : Conductor<IScreen> , IMainMenuViewModel
{
    public bool CanDoAction1
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void DoAction1()
    {
        //perform action
    }
}
```

How do I inject it into a parent view model? The IMainMenuViewModel interface doesn't specify any of the Conductor properties, so I can't use it in the place of an IScreen and this fails:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IShellViewModel
{
    public ShellViewModel(IMainMenuViewModel mainMenuViewModel)
    {
        ActivateItem(mainMenuViewModel); //mainMenuViewModel is not an IScreen
    }
}
```

Is the correct thing to do to inherit IScreen in my view model interfaces? I.e:

```
public interface IMainMenuViewModel : IScreen
{
    bool CanDoAction1 { get; }
    void DoAction1();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I sugest read http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/ 
An Injection Constructor should do no more than receiving the dependencies.
You should Active MainMenuViewModel in OnInitialize or OnActivate method. Of course you may inherit IScreen in you  ViewModel.